# Sum of quasi-m-accretive operators

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

Kato's existence theory (see [link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0067080)) gives conditions under which a PDE has a (unique) solution. The equation of evolution he considers is
$$ \frac{dv}{dt} + A(v)v = f(v),$$
where $A(y) \in L(Y,X)$ for $y \in X$ and $X,Y$ are Hilbert spaces. One of the conditions he requires is that $A(y)$ is quasi-$m$-accretive uniformly on bounded sets in $Y$.

> > Is it true that if $A$ and $B$ are both quasi-m-accretive uniformly on bounded sets in $Y$, then their sum $A + B$ is also quasi-m-accretive uniformly on bounded sets in $Y$?

Comment: This question has received only very little attention so far -- maybe you wish to edit.

Comment: Woah how did you find this, I barely remembered asking this